# "Leading order error" vs "order of the error"

Tags: numerical-methods

This may be a daft question but I wanted to be sure. If I were asked to find the *leading* order error when using the mid-point rule to approximate a function $f(x)$  would it be the same as being asked to find the order of the error in the midpoint rule?